# Using onmouseover in html? Image

Tags: html

I want to enlarge my picture using `onmouserover` but it is not working in my second code. Any help would be aprreciated.

**Working:**

```
<img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images.logo.gif" width="200" height="100" onmouseover="this.height=160;this.width=235;" onmouseout="this.height=100;this.width=200" />
```

**Not Working:**

```
echo "<img src='../../img/Photos/Users/".$row['PICTURE']."' style='width: 30px; height: 30px;'
onmouseover='this.height=160;this.width=235;' onmouseout='this.height=100;this.width=200' />";
```

Comment: why negative point :/

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
echo "<img src='../../img/Photos/Users/".$row['PICTURE']."' style='width: 30px; height: 30px;' onmouseover='this.style.height=160;this.style.width=235;' onmouseout='this.style.height=100;this.style.width=200' />";
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! in general, code-only answers are discouraged... can you add some explanation?